# How to remove the *.compiled Files from bin folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to deploy my website with precompiled views, for performance reasons. So I have configured `UseMerge` and `PrecompileBeforePublish`.

This is part of my publishing profile:

```
<PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
<EnableUpdateable>False</EnableUpdateable>
<UseMerge>True</UseMerge>
<SingleAssemblyName>Conwell.Administration.Views</SingleAssemblyName>
<DeleteAppCodeCompiledFiles>True</DeleteAppCodeCompiledFiles>
```

In the UI this is reflected:

[image: checkbox]

My `Conwell.Administration.Views.dll` gets successfull created. However after publishing, I have for each View an additional `.precompiled` file in my bin folder:

[image: *.compiled files]

The content reads as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<preserve resultType="2" virtualPath="/Areas/Bookings/Views/SepaDebits/Detail.cshtml" hash="fffffffff9d57aef" filehash="1737cd4f2d0e" flags="110000" assembly="Conwell.Administration.Views" type="ASP._Page_Areas_Bookings_Views_SepaDebits_Detail_cshtml">
  <filedeps>
    <filedep name="/Areas/Bookings/Views/SepaDebits/Detail.cshtml" />
  </filedeps>
</preserve>
```

I tried to simple delete them, but then the website shows only a blank page. I don't like that many `*.compiled` files. They add up to more than thousand.

For what are they used? ViewEngine? Is it somehow possible to disable them? Maybe a custom ViewEngine?

I have only found [this thread](https://forums.asp.net/t/2020180.aspx?Publish+of+MVC+app+includes+compiled+files+in+bin+) so far, but it doesn't give any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For executable files in an ASP.NET Web application, the compiler
>   assemblies and files with the .compiled file name extension. The
>   assembly name is generated by the compiler. The .compiled file does
>   not contain executable code. Instead, it contains only the information
>   that ASP.NET needs to find the appropriate assembly.
>
> After the precompiled application is deployed, ASP.NET uses the
>   assemblies in the Bin folder to process requests. The precompilation
>   output includes .aspx or .asmx files as placeholders for pages. The
>   placeholder files contain no code. They exist only to provide a way to
>   invoke ASP.NET for a specific page request and so that file
>   permissions can be set to restrict access to the pages.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e22s60h9(v=vs.85).aspx

You will have to remove the pre-compile steps to remove them, or deploy the source code alone. Use build server to compile real time.

I would just leave them. They cause no harm.

Comment: So this is a ASP/IIS runtime thing, nothing that can be influenced by code?

Comment: Unfortunately no. At least I have not been able to find a way. Sorry